# Ionic 2 (click) se dispara dos veces

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, iphone

Estoy desarrollando una app con Ionic 2, pero me encontré con el problema con el evento click al momento de probar la aplicación en un dispositivo, en este caso es un iphone.

Este es el código que utilizo para generar una alerta, es simple pero se dispara dos veces.

home.html

```
<div padding>
    <button ion-button full (click)="TestAlert()">Alert</button>
</div>
```

home.ts

```
TestAlert(){

     console.log('Hola');
     alert('Hola');
  }
```

Si alguien sabe si es problema de cofiguración del framework o tiene el mismo problema y lo resolvió, me sería de gran ayuda.

También les comparto el ejemplo de lo que estoy haciendo en este [repositorio](https://github.com/jorgemejia/PersonalProject2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguien respondió la mima pregunta en la página en inglés.

La solución es utulizar (tap) en lugar de (click) y si se sigue teniendo problemas actualizar ionic a la versión 3.1.1.

Comment: Jorge si eso soluciona el problema. Marca tu respuesta como aceptada para que pueda ayudar en el futuro a otros usuarios. ;)